# building javascript bundle: 0%

Tags: javascript, react-native, bundle, expo

i am working on expo. When i run the command "npm start", the expo developer tool gets open and the tunnel gets connected but the javascript bundle gets stuck on 0%. and does not load further. why is it happening?

[image]

Comment: are you using watchman ?

Comment: No.............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please delete the /node_modules folder and package-lock.json file

OR

may be a Watchman version issue.

https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/issues/513#issuecomment-371102947

Please refer to this link.

Comment: it worked for the first time but now i am again having issues. it does build when i run the expo app first time but as long as i start to do any coding it doesnot build anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions

Log out of Expo
Shutdown DevTool (browser thing)
Reboot Windows

Helped me a lot!